# What is most effective and fastest way to remove string from beginning? (PHP micro-optimisation)

Tags: php, regex, micro-optimization

I have a string like `www.host.com` and I need to remove beginning from it (in this case `www.`) to make it just `host.com`. There is array of these beginnings (like: `m.`, `wap.` and so on). How to do it in effective and fast way?

Currently I am using this code, but I think there should be a better/faster/cleaner way:

```
<?php

function _without_start( $val, $start )
{
    if( _starts( $val, $start ) )
    {
        $len = mb_strlen( $start );
        $val = mb_substr( $val, $len );
    }

    return $val;
}

function _starts( $str, $needle ) 
{
    return ( mb_substr( $str, 0, mb_strlen($needle) ) === $needle );
}

/********************************************/

$host = 'www.host.com';

$remove_from_beginning = array( 'www.', 'wap.', 'admin.' );
foreach( $remove_from_beginning as $start )
{
    $host = _without_start( $host, $start );
}

var_dump( $host );
```

Comment: use `explode` and `in_array`, not a regex.

Answer (score 2):

You dont need foreach for removing somethings from string, this one will be better,

```
$url = preg_replace("/^(www|wap)\./si","","www.wap.com");
echo $url;
```

Answer (score 1):

With `explode` and `in_array`:

```
function _without_start($host, $prefixes) {
    list($prefix, $remainder) = explode('.', $host, 2);
    return in_array($prefix, $prefixes) ? $remainder : $host;
}

$prefixes = ['www', 'wap', 'admin'];
$host = 'www.host.com';

echo _without_start($host, $prefixes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you added a <kbd>Regex</kbd> tag you can make a list using **alteration** in regex and check it against the string and replace with `empty` string.

**Regex:** `^(www|admin|wap)\.`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uE4qZ1/1)**

Answer (score 0):

If you are up for a `regex` based solution (as one of the tag mentions `regex`), here you go

```
$remove_from_beginning = array( 'www.', 'wap.', 'admin.' );
$final = "";

foreach( $remove_from_beginning as $start )
{
    $final = $final . "" . substr_replace($start, '', -1) . "" . "\.|";
}

$final = substr_replace($final, '', -1);

echo preg_replace("/" . "" . "(?:" . "" . $final . "" . ")" . "" . "(.*)" . "" . "/", "$1", "www.exaple.com");
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/1dZTbM)**